# inquiry for self hosting and HERE XYZ

Tags: here-api, here-maps-rest

We are currently using HERE technologies for our routing & navigation product for on demand bus service.
We are invited to run on demand bus service in an industrial complex. The area is privately run. There are 2 specific requirement which will determine routing and navigation solution that we use for the on demand bus service in that complex:

1. Able to maintain and update map details in the industrial complex quickly and easily. Map within the industrial complex will be maintained by the industrial complex administrator. They will update or draw their own map as and when new road are built or changed. And it should reflect immediately (in very short lead time) for routing and navigation purpose.
2. Map details must not be open to public.

We are currently using HERE Map for turn by turn navigation and route planning. However, we are referring to public map which is hosted by HERE map. And also any changes of map details will subject to normal process and lead time of here map creator 
https://mapcreator.here.com/

Please help to check whether or not any of HERE product allowing us to have full control of map update and not open to public. It is also important to make sure the version of map can be linked to route planning and turn by turn navigation (Android Mobile SDK).

The product that we think potentially can fit into this requirement are 
HERE XYZ  -- https://www.here.xyz/
& 
https://www.here.com/products/location-based-services/self-hosting

Please help to double confirm if we can still use HERE Technologies product and services for such project requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, self hosting the HERE Map data and Location services is possible. Like stated on our page:

> When businesses require more control of their data and infrastructure environment, then uploading to a public cloud is not an option. HERE offers a variety of location services that can be hosted on your own privately controlled infrastructure, on your preferred public cloud provider, or both. We aim to meet your exact needs – whether you’re building a new solution or integrating location functionality into an existing platform.

Please contact HERE Sales with your use case:
 
https://www.here.com/products/location-based-services/self-hosting?form_id=1811&cta_id=21096_contact-us&detailed_source=www.here.com%2Fproducts%2Flocation-based-services%2Fself-hosting